# Google Service Account Delegation 404 error

Tags: google-apps-script, service-accounts

I am attempting to authenticate with a service account to work on behalf of a user account on the domain. I have delegated admin access and added to the GSuite console. I can get an access token with the below but the making batch requests to copy drive files returns "code: 404, message: 'File not found:". The below code is writted in Google Apps Script. Am I missing something form the process to creating and authenticating the service account?

```
    var CREDENTIALS = {
      private_key: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- XXXXXXX \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      client_email: "XXXXXX@fXXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      client_id: "1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      user_email: "XXXXX@XXXX.XXX.XXX",
      scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]
    };


    function oAuthToken(){
          var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token";
          var header = {
            alg: "RS256",
            typ: "JWT",
          };
          var now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
          var claim = {
            iss: CREDENTIALS.client_id,
            sub: CREDENTIALS.user_email,
            scope: CREDENTIALS.scopes.join(" "),
            aud: url,
            exp: (now + 3600).toString(),
            iat: now.toString(),
          };
          var signature = Utilities.base64Encode(JSON.stringify(header)) + "." + Utilities.base64Encode(JSON.stringify(claim));
          var jwt = signature + "." + Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(signature, CREDENTIALS.private_key));

          var params = {
            method: "post",
            payload: {
              assertion: jwt,
              grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
            },
          };
          var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getContentText();
          return JSON.parse(res)
        }
```

The batch process is a bit rough but this is the gist of it.

```
var request={
  batchPath:
  requests:[]
}

var backoff =0

function batch(request) {
  var oAuth=oAuthToken().access_token
  var url ='https://www.googleapis.com/'+request.batchPath
  var body =request.requests
  if(body.length<1){
    return []
  }
  var boundary = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
  var contentId = 0;
  var data = '--' + boundary + '\r\n';

  for (var i in body) {
    if(typeof body[i]=='object'){
      data += 'Content-Type: application/http\r\n';
      data += 'Content-ID: ' + ++contentId + '\r\n\r\n';
      data += body[i].method + ' ' + body[i].endpoint + '\r\n';
      data += body[i].requestBody ? 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n' : '\r\n';
      data += body[i].requestBody ? JSON.stringify(body[i].requestBody) + '\r\n' : '';
      data += "--" + boundary + '\r\n';
    }
  }

  var parseBatchRes = function(res) {
    var splittedRes = res.split('--batch');
    return splittedRes.slice(1, splittedRes.length - 1).map(function(e) {
      return {
        contentId: Number(e.match(/Content-ID: response-(\d+)/)[1]),
        status: Number(e.match(/HTTP\/\d+.\d+ (\d+)/)[1]),
        object: JSON.parse(e.match(/{[\S\s]+}/)[0]),
      };
    });
  };

  var payload = Utilities.newBlob(data).getBytes();
  var head = {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + oAuth}
  var options = {
    method: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'multipart/mixed; boundary=' + boundary,
    payload: payload,
    headers: head,
    muteHttpExceptions: false
  };
  var complete=false;
  var finalResponse=[];
  for (var n=0; n<=backoff; n++) {
    if(complete){
      break;
    }
    var complete = true
    console.log('backoff',n);
    var response =UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
    for(var j=0;j<response.length;j++){
      if(response[r].status!=200){
        var complete = false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `the making batch requests to copy drive files`?

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike I've added the batch process in. The file ids to copy are coming from an advanced services call to var files = Drive.Files.list({
      q: query,
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about your scripts of `oAuthToken()` and `batch(request)`? Did you refer your script from other user's script? If you reffered other script, can you provide the URL of the site and/or thread of the original one? Because if you have modified the original script, I would like to confirm the difference between the original and your current script. I thought that by this, it might confirm the modification points. How about this?

Comment: Hi there @ClaySmith, does the file you are trying to copy *exist* and moreover, do you have access to it?

Comment: @Tanaike It's a variation of your work. oAuthToken() https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/12/07/retrieving-access-token-for-service-account-using-google-apps-script/        batch()  https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f167b9280a8e710804e4061571b53fb9

Comment: @ale13 Thanks. Yes the file id's I've tried indicate a folder on a shared drive. I have added the service account as a Content manager to the shared drive. The tool is working  to copy files which are approiately tagged from a Google Personal drive to a shared drive. The standard of dragging the folder is not the prefered method because file content is not all in a ready state. The service account and others like it will be used for other things so I'm also trying to better understand the creation and use.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I had never noticed that you are using my sample script. I apologize for this. From your replying, I would like to check the differences.

Comment: Here is a sample of the batch request: {"batchPath":"batch/drive/v3","requests":[{"method":"POST","endpoint":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1XkUcGLFP83bMgXb1UKGJP4iUsbUSsPwA/copy","requestBody":{"parents":["16k_MPR3hfz5xlMd608kRTU33IllXGL7k"],"name":"WorldLanguages_Grades6-12_Week11_Part4_La Vida en Cusco.pptx"}}]

Comment: The request works fine when using ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() but hits rate limit quotas.

Comment: I added supportsAllDrives=true to the copy request and i'm not getting 500 Internal error messages with content copying appropriately. I was expecting 200 to be able to mark that the file was successfully copied. I'm at a loss.

Comment: This issue has been solved with by adding the supportsAllDrives=true url query parameter to the request. Because content was moving from a personal Drive to a Shared drive all drives needed to be supported in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `supportsAllDrives = true` query parameter to the request.

The parameters indicates whether the requesting application supports both My Drives and shared drives and the default value for this is `false`.

**Reference**

- [Drive API Parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#parameters)